# How to implement API key authentication in Symfony 6

Tags: php, api-key, symfony6

I have been struggling with implementing API key authentication in my Symfony project, even after reading through various available documentation. The code I've been provided with by other developers also hasn't helped me. It's possible that I'm having trouble understanding the documentation or properly implementing the code myself. However, I am not interested in using more complex authentication methods like JWT or OAUTH, and would prefer to use a simple API key authentication system. I am hoping someone can provide me with a clear and easy-to-follow solution or guidance on how to properly implement API key authentication in Symfony.

The API is already online and I wanted to make it more private by adding this type of authentication, so only the people who has the key can access the data on the endpoints. The key would be stored somewhere in the database, and only used by people that I provide the key.

Comment: It looks like the following doc covers exacly your needs https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authenticator.html

Comment: @Nek thanks for the reply, Ive read that document plenty of times, do you have any example I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but I hope it can help someone.

The documentation actually lacks a bit of details. When using the given authenticator, you should configure a user provider to fetch users by their apiKey property.

Or you can provide a callback to the UserBadge object that will be used to fetch the user (instead of the user provider).

[Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/Heyfara/401e10d99466865e606d5324180b6d02) with a bit more details.